# Can I pass arguments to a .js script on Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript

I'm starting to get a handle of Geth, especially the scripts, following [this](https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/example_script.html) and [this](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/accessing-contracts-and-transactions.html).

I have scripts that create contracts and call functions, but I don't know how to pass arguments to a script. `Argv[]` is not recognized, and most javascript doc I found is for html.

For now I call scripts with `geth --testnet js script.js 2>>geth.log`

Is there a way to pass arguments ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT :** I will leave my old answer for legacy, but user [BokkyPooBah](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/1268/bokkypoobah) gave me an awesome answer to another problem, somewhat related to this one.

His solution solved both, so go give him points on his answer [there](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11185/how-can-i-run-scripted-geth-commands-with-specified-command-line-parameters) !

I'll quickly sum it up here:

You need to have an instance of Geth running, and with a bash script instead of running `geth --testnet js script.js 2>>geth.log` you'll use `geth attach`. You can then write javascript directly, and use `$1` and `$2` like in any bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
arg1=$1
arg2=$2
geth attach << EOF | grep "Data: " | sed "s/Data: //"

<content of your js script>

EOF
```

This will hide the console output. If you need to see it for debugging, use `geth attach << EOF` instead.

You may need to add the path to you ipc file if it's not default, between `geth` and `attach`. I tried to be short but if you need more detailed explanation see his answer.

---

*My question was not perfectly asked and isn't clear about what I needed. I tried to be general, but since there is "no easy way" to pass arguments to a js script, you have to find a trick that is very dependent on the way you're calling your script (as I said, there are very specific answers for when the script is called from a html).*

*I found a solution to my problem so I'll post the answer because I think it could be useful to others.*

*What I was doing was calling a simple bash script from a web page, which executed `geth --testnet script.js`, so I already had two levels of scripts : bash and javascript. Js can't take arguments (easily), but bash scripts can.*

*So here's what I did. The following is my bash script file.*

```
echo "primary = eth.accounts[0]; personal.unlockAccount ...<content of the js script> ... address ='"$1"'); ..." > gethScript.js
geth --testnet js gethScript.js 2>>gethScript.log
```

*The argument is $1 and is written directly in the js script. Then the js script works perfectly as if the argument was hard coded. The bash script can be run from console with `bash bashScript "0x00..00"` or in php for example with : `exec('./bashScript '.$address);`*

Answer (score 5):

The best way, and the one i would recommend to you, to handle scripts in geth is.

1. First: start geth with console. Forget for now scripts.
2. Then in console use command: `loadScript("source");`

That way if you got for example this simple script:

```
function getBalance(fromAddress)
{
var Balance = web3.fromWei(web3.getBalance(fromAddress), "ether");
console.log(Balance)
}
```

in a file named `myScripts.js` (in which you can have more functions), you would do that:

- Load geth console.
- `loadScript('home/TeleportingGoat/Desktop/Scripts/myScript.js');`
- `getBalance('0x1231afd1289a...deff');`

That's the way i would suggest you to procceed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you you call console commands from outsite geth ? I know how to call geth scripts from shell, but I don't know how to use console commands from the outside... The script isn't there to save me time but to automate a process, I can't touch the console myself.

Comment: There are just few ways:
JSON-RPC API, WEB3.JS API, etc etc... check this [Ethereum Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki) for the whole documentation. The easier and most used is web3.js

Comment: I found a solution to my problem (that I posted) but my question was a little general so yours technically answer my question, I'm not sure which one I should accept.

Comment: oh, now i understand what were you asking about exactly :)
nice way to solve it :)