# How do I exit geth scripts?

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript

Sometimes in the scripts I run there are errors (for example one variable is `undefined`), and geth doesn't stop, it tries to run every line of the script, throwing errors everywhere.

I want to abort the script if I detect an error, but I don't how I can do that, the usual javascript functions don't work here. `exit()` (or `exit`) gives `ReferenceError: 'exit' not defined`, which is weird because when I'm in the console `exit` works fine.

How do I exit the script ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Most likely you should not scripts in the geth console in the first place. Instead you want to run your JavaScript within Node.js that connects gets. Please see this answer: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11203/620

Answer (score 2):

With [ethereum-console](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereum-console) you can use `process.exit()`.